# Put result of code right below the code in resulting PDF. Haskell

Tags: haskell, literate-programming

Is there any way to execute code in a .lhs file and put the result right below the code itself in the resulting PDF?

For example:

```
[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Do you mean automatically evaluate expressions which aren't declarations, and paste the results back into the source code before it's turned into a pdf, a bit like Mathematica does?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It's for showing an example of how a function works, and I want to be executed if anyone runs the code and also to be shown if anyone looks at the PDF

Comment: Surely, you're gonna need a bit more control about what will be output, or are you not going to use any un-printable definitions? Why not use e.g. [`HaTeX`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX), perhaps together with [a suitable quasi-quoter](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-October/049244.html) to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using LaTeX, you can use [lhs2TeX](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/). Here is a simple example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

%include polycode.fmt
%options ghci

\begin{document}

< [1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]

This evaluates to \eval{[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]}.

> x = [1 .. 6]

And this evaluates to \eval{x}, too.

\end{document}
```

This will run GHCi with the source file as input in the background.
You can thus evaluate expressions using `\eval` in the context of the current (literate Haskell) module,
and their results will be spliced into the resulting `.tex` sources.